# How can Outlook addin detect when an account is removed

Tags: c#, outlook, outlook-addin

I get accounts from Outlook like below.

```
    Outlook.NameSpace ns = null;
    Outlook.Accounts accounts = null;
    Outlook.Account account = null;
    string accountList = string.Empty;

    try
    {
        ns = OutlookApp.Session;
        accounts = ns.Accounts;
        for (int i = 1; i <= accounts.Count; i++)
        {
            account = accounts[i];
            accountList += String.Format("{0} - {1}{2}", 
                account.UserName,  
                account.SmtpAddress, 
                Environment.NewLine);
            if (account != null)
                Marshal.ReleaseComObject(account);
        }
        MessageBox.Show(accountList);
    }
    finally
    {
        if (accounts != null)
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(accounts);
        if (ns != null)
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(ns);
    }
```

However, Outlook return accounts, including those that have been removed.
It seems that there are no events that occur when the account is removed.

After the account is removed, is there a way to get the accounts excluding the removed account? How I can get accounts excluding removed account?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the MAPI level (C++ or Delphi), account events are implemented through [IOlkAccountManager::Advise](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/outlook/auxiliary/iolkaccountmanager-advise) method. You can see the events fire in [OutlookSpy](http://www.dimastr.com/outspy/) (I am its author - click IOlkAccountManager button, go to the Advise tab.

Outlook Object Model does not expose these events. If using [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption) (I am also its author) is an option, it exposes all account events through the [RDOAccounts](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/RDOAccounts.htm) object - `AccountChange, AccountAdd, AccountRemove, AccountBeforeRemove, AccountOrderChange`.

Answer (score 0):

The Outlook object model doesn't provide any event for that. The best what you can do is to handle the [Stores.BeforeStoreRemove](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.stores.beforestoreremove?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev11.query%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbaol11.chm2754)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue%26f%3D255%26MSPPError%3D-2147217396) event which is fired when a `Store` is about to be removed from the current session either programmatically or through user action. Here is what MSDN says for the event:

---

Outlook must be running in order for this event to fire. This event will fire when any of the following occurs:

- A store is removed by the user clicking the `Close` command on the Shortcut menu.
- A store is removed programmatically by calling `Namespace.RemoveStore`.

This event will not fire when any of the following occurs:

- When Outlook shuts down and closes a primary or delegate store.
- If a store is removed through the Mail applet in the Microsoft Windows Control Panel and Outlook is not running.
- A delegate store is removed on the Advanced tab of the Microsoft Exchange Server dialog box.
- A store is removed through the Data Files tab of the Account Manager dialog box when Outlook is not running.
- An IMAP Store is removed from the profile.

You can use this event to determine that a store has been removed, and take appropriate actions if the store is required for your application (such as remounting the store). Otherwise you would have to resort to polling the Stores collection.